# Shift bits left in .asm for PIC18

Tags: assembly, shift, bit, pic18

I'm trying to shift bits left in `.asm` via the *rlcf* by rotating, and then clearing the carry. Is this going to work? If not, can I get some help? For some reason this won't compile and it's driving me crazy, this is such a simple program yet I can't get it. 
All help greatly appreciated.

```
count equ 0x20
byte equ 0x21

;shift right

movlw b'11111110'
movwf byte
bcf STATUS,C
rlcf Byte ;for left shift
bcf STATUS,C
loop
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that shift left X by 1 is exactly X + X -- use the add (`addwf`) instruction.

Comment: we're required to use the rotate function, which essentially should be the same, correct?

Comment: hm, should work then maybe im not loading settings or something. thank you

Comment: See Paul R's comment as well -- the assembler is case sensitive.